# Mount a NTFS Raid0 disk under linux debian

Tags: linux, raid, mount, software-raid, mdadm

In my new laptop I have a a RAID 0 configuration with a normal disk and a smaller SSD drive. I have removed the dvd bay and replaced the dvd player with a 256 GB SSD drive where I run linux debian. I have configured dual boot between Windows 8.1 which was provided in the base configuration and debian linux jessie. Everything is running fine. However my ssd drive is running out of space and I would like to mount the RAID0 NTFS disks under linux. My problem is that I'm not completely sure how to do it

After a brief investigation I have issued the following commands

**fdisk -l** output

```
Disk /dev/sda: 298.1 GiB, 320072933376 bytes, 625142448 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x6a17bc42

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *         2048 167774207 167772160    80G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2       167774208 625135615 457361408 218.1G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT

Disk /dev/sdc: 29.8 GiB, 32017047552 bytes, 62533296 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk /dev/sdb: 232.9 GiB, 250059350016 bytes, 488397168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x0913cd0f

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1            2048 472852479 472850432 225.5G 83 Linux
/dev/sdb2       472854526 488396799  15542274   7.4G  5 Extended
/dev/sdb5       472854528 488396799  15542272   7.4G 82 Linux swap/Solaris
```

**lscpi -vv** relevant configuration

```
00:1f.2 RAID bus controller: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile SATA Controller [RAID mode] (rev 04)
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 1993
Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
Status: Cap+ 66MHz+ UDF- FastB2B+ ParErr- DEVSEL=medium >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
Latency: 0
Interrupt: pin B routed to IRQ 45
Region 0: I/O ports at 30a8 [size=8]
Region 1: I/O ports at 30b4 [size=4]
Region 2: I/O ports at 30a0 [size=8]
Region 3: I/O ports at 30b0 [size=4]
Region 4: I/O ports at 3060 [size=32]
Region 5: Memory at d073c000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2K]
Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Address: fee0c00c  Data: 4122
Capabilities: [70] Power Management version 3
    Flags: PMEClk- DSI- D1- D2- AuxCurrent=0mA PME(D0-,D1-,D2-,D3hot+,D3cold-)
    Status: D0 NoSoftRst+ PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=0 PME-
Capabilities: [a8] SATA HBA v1.0 BAR4 Offset=00000004
Kernel driver in use: ahci
```

This is my **cat /proc/partitions** output

```
major minor  #blocks  name
8        0  312571224 sda
8       32   31266648 sdc
8       16  244198584 sdb
8       17  236425216 sdb1
8       21    7771136 sdb5
```

This is my **cat /proc/mdstat** output

```
Personalities : 
md126 : inactive sda[0](S)
      2128 blocks super external:imsm

md127 : inactive sdc[0](S)
      2772 blocks super external:imsm

unused devices: <none>
```

This is my **mdadm -D /dev/md126** and **mdadm -D /dev/md127** output

```
/dev/md126:
Version : imsm
Raid Level : container
Total Devices : 1
Working Devices : 1
UUID : 806e6778:fa1107b0:aeb7aff1:296bcdb9
Member Arrays :
Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice
   0       8        0        -        /dev/sda

/dev/md127:
Version : imsm
Raid Level : container
Total Devices : 1
Working Devices : 1
UUID : ea548bde:d7a7e0fb:ab71c32e:1c109924
Member Arrays :
Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice
   0       8       32        -        /dev/sdc
```

My understanding from this [link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/139271/how-to-get-details-of-raid-devices-both-soft-and-hard) and from the output of the commands presented is that I have a software raid configuration. Also from this [link](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=833653) I think I have to issue a mdadm command and them mount the device. Something like this from the mentioned thread:

```
sudo mdadm --build /dev/md0 --chunk=64 --level=0 --raid-devices=2    /dev/sdd2 /dev/sdc2
sudo mkdir /media/Windows
sudo mount -t ntfs /dev/md0 /media/Windows
```

As I have said I'm not completely sure of the parameters for my case and also how do I add the configuration to the fstab to allow a mount after login.

Comment: duplicate of : http://superuser.com/questions/377646/how-do-i-mount-a-software-raid1-mirror-created-by-windows-in-linux-using-mdadm

Comment: Thanks for your answer and link but RAID1 (mirror) is different from RAID0(stripe) at least in terms of what they achieve. Can I assume that it's not possible also for RAID 0 ? There's several answers that say it's possible...

Comment: Do not change your current setup to RAID0 with the existing disks.  You'll destroy all the data that exists on them.  Instead, use a folder redirect to a spare hard drive, or invest in a real storage system or NAS.